# How to use multiple destination port in single NSG SecurityRule in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, network-security-groups

I want to use single securityRule in NSG instead of separate rule for each destination port.

I have used destinationPortRanges with multiple ports in below template instead of destinationPortRange with single ports.

```
{
    "name": "test-nsg-005",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
    "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
    "location": "[variables('location')]",
    "properties": {
        "securityRules": [                {
                "name": "Allow ports",
                "properties": {
                    "priority": 1000,
                    "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                    "protocol": "TCP",
                    "destinationPortRanges": [
                        "22",
                        "443"                            
                    ],
                    "access": "Allow",
                    "direction": "Inbound",
                    "sourcePortRange": "*",
                    "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
                }
            }]
    }
}
```

When I try to run the above template using Azure CLI, I am unable to proceed due to the following error

> The template deployment 'test' is not valid according to the
>   validation procedure. The tracking id is
>   '0ee64525-9d2b-49cb-bac7-24baa73ac1d7'. See inner errors for details.
>   Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.

Update:-

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The template deployment \'test\' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is \'1e7527bc-6c7f-4aa9-8ed6-235402a229b7\'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.","details":[{"code":"InvalidResourceName","message":"Resource name Allow ports is invalid. The name can be up to 80 characters long. It must begin with a word character, and it must end with a word character or with \'_\'. The name may contain word characters or \'.\', \'-\', \'_\'.","details":[]}]}}'
msrest.exceptions : The template deployment 'test' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '1e7527bc-6c7f-4aa9-8ed6-235402a229b7'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.
```

I got the above error, After renaming the security rule name, issue got resolved.

Comment: this is the right way to do that, one thing, try using an array of integers, not strings: `[ 22, 443]`

Comment: @4c74356b41 Still same issue after changing from strings to integers.

Comment: Do I have to change destinationAddressPrefix to destinationAddressPrefixes?

Comment: no, you dont. show the real error

Comment: It is working now with ports as both string and integer. There was an issue with name of the security rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was due to the bad security rule name.